# Laravel project hosting error in heroku using postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, postgresql, heroku

I'm making a flight reservation in laravel and I published it on Heroku. I used MySQL for the database when I was on the development, but when I want to publish it on Heroku, they dont have MySQL so I used PostgreSQL. I watched some videos on how to host it using that database.

When I was done, I can do CRUD in the hosting site but when Im going to filter the flight schedules it gives me an error. But when I do a search in my localhost, It doesnt have any errors.

I think this error is in the I used which is PostgreSQL. How can I fix this?

The result when I search on localhost
[image: The result when I search]

The result when I search on Heroku
[image]

My filter method in the controller.

`FlightsController.php`

```
 public function searchFlights(Request $request){
        $flights =  Flights::where('flight_country_from', 'like', '%' . $request->flightFrom . '%')
            ->where('flight_country_from', 'like', '%' . $request->flightFrom . '%')
            ->where('flight_country_to', 'like', '%' . $request->flightTo . '%')
            ->whereDate('flight_schedule', 'like', '%' . $request->flightDepart . '%')
            ->paginate(5);

            return view('airways.flightresult', compact('flights'));

    }
```

my search form

`Search.blade.php`

```
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="flights" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="flights-tab">
          <h2 class="text-4 mb-3">Book Domestic and International Flights</h2>
          <form method="GET"  autocomplete="off" id="bookingFlight" action="{{url("/flightSearch")}}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <div class="form-row">
             <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-3 form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="flightFrom" id="flightFrom"  placeholder="From">
                <span class="icon-inside"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-3 form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="flightTo" id="flightTo"  placeholder="To">
                <span class="icon-inside"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-3 form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="flightDepart"  id="flightDepart" required required placeholder="Departure Date">
                <span class="icon-inside"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>
             </div>
          </div>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "whereDate('flight_schedule', 'like', '%' . $request->flightDepart . '%')" What exactly are you trying to achieve with this line? Should not it be whereDate('flight_schedule', '=',$request->flightDepart) or something like this?

Comment: its a syntax for my filtering sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise you to use the same database in development and production. MySQL and PostgreSQL aren't drop-in replacements for each other.

Either

- switch to Postgres locally, reproduce the error, and fix it, or
- use a supported [MySQL add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#data-stores) like ClearDB or JawsDB in production.

Comment: If I use ClearDB it requires me to pay. Maybe the solution for this sir is to find a free hosting that supports mysq? Am I right?

Comment: @Vince, yes, either choose a free provider or pay for one. ClearDB and JawsDB both have a free tier but it's fairly limited so maybe that's not enough for you. Amazon RDS supports MySQL and [its free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/) is more generous. There are certainly other options too.